# Button alignment not set in asp buttons & Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a asp button and a button dropdown list. The problem is my button dropdown always goes to below the other buttons.I want that button to the other button row.

Here I paste the screenshot of the current buttons(dropdown take it from **Bootstrap 2.3** )

[image: buttons]

My Coding Goes here

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <a href="#" class="alert-link">
        <p align="right">
            Welcome <%=GetUserName()%>
            (Admin Level)
    </a>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUsr" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" OnClick="btnUsr_Click" Text="User Management"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload Files" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnlogout" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" OnClick="btnlogout_Click" Text="LogOut" />

    <li class="dropdown" style="list-style: none;">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary">More <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="SendSMS.aspx">Send SMS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="CommonPageManagement.aspx">Manage Pages & Sections</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <br />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting your buttons between `ul` tags. I haven't tested this but try something like:

```
<ul>
     <li><asp:Button ID="btnUsr" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" OnClick="btnUsr_Click" Text="User Management"/></li>
     <li><asp:Button ID="btnUpload" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload Files" /></li>
     <li><asp:Button ID="btnlogout" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" OnClick="btnlogout_Click" Text="LogOut" /></li>
     <li class="dropdown" style="list-style: none;">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="SendSMS.aspx">Send SMS</a>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="CommonPageManagement.aspx">Manage Pages & Sections</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

I think bootstrap has a `class` or `id` you could use to make the `ul` display as a row.
Additionally, you could mix in your own css with that of bootstrap, but I think you should be careful with that, because this could conflict with the css from bootstrap.

Comment: @Techguy, any success yet? If you solved your problem, please share!

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap a content to row class :

```
<div class="row">
... content  ...
</div>
```

If you want to align content to right just use **pull-right** class instead of `p align`.

I'd suggest to read through a bootstrap documentation where you can find grid system description.

Comment: But still my Button Dropdown shows below the other buttons